# Update Item from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to work out how to update an item that is stored in my Firebase. I've managed to get it to a point where I can create and remove items. I'd now like to edit and update an existing item. My items are repeated on the page, and each of them have an "Edit" button next to them.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" ng-model="editedProvider.title">
  <button type="submit" ng-click="updateProvider(provider.name)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm adding items to my list like so:

**JS**

```
$scope.newProvider = {};
$scope.providers = [];

providersRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
    $scope.providers.push({
      title: snapshotVal.title,
      name: snapshot.name()
    });
  });
});

// Create Item
$scope.createProvider = function() {
  var newProvider = {
    title: $scope.title,
  };
  providersRef.push(newProvider);
};
```

I can't work out how to update this item. I've got an update provider function that looks like this:

```
$scope.updateProvider = function(name) {
  providersRef.child(name).update({
    title: snapshotVal.title
  });
};
```

But that shows this error in the console:

> Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

I've tried creating a function that finds the uses the `snapshot.name()` to check it against the item I'm editing to update the `title` with the new value, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I've set up a [Plunker over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Azq4jXrrK268KzNfFmLn?p=preview). Any help with what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: When I update a hospital in that plunker, I get an error message in the console. Please include this error message in your question as people shouldn't have to go to your plunker to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant HTML from your view is this:

```
  <div ng-show="shouldShowEditing()">
    <h3>Editing {{ editedProvider.title }}</h3>
    <form role="form" name="addPlaceForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" ng-model="editedProvider.title">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="updateProvider(provider.name)">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelEditing();">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

The relevant code is this:

```
$scope.updateProvider = function(name) {
  console.log('updateProvider: '+name);
  providersRef.child(name).update({
    title: snapshotVal.title
  });
};
```

I added that console.log statement, because it shows you easily what is going wrong. The output is:

> updateProvider: undefined

So from that you can see that you're not passing in the provider's name correctly. With this knowledge, you can go back to the HTML and see that you're refering to `provider.name` in there, where the rest of that form refers to `editedProvider`.

So the fix is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="updateProvider(editedProvider.name)">Submit</button>
```

### Update

With the name-passing problem solved, the next error message is:

> ReferenceError: snapshotVal is not defined

Which is also quite clear: your `updateProvider` code looks copy/pasted from one of the Firebase listeners and is referencing a non-existant `snapshotVal`. Instead, it should be getting the new title from the Angular scope:

```
$scope.updateProvider = function(name) {
  providersRef.child(name).update({
    title: $scope.editedProvider.title
  });
};
```

Comment: I've made those corrections but it doesn't seem to be updating the item title... Am I missing something here? Also, when you say use the console are you speaking about the console in Chrome's Developer Tools or does Plunker have it's own console built in?

Comment: Wait! I think I've got it. Would this work? `providersRef.child(name).update({ title: $scope.editedProvider.title });` Would that be the correct way to update an item?

Comment: Your plunker still contains the mistake I pointed out. Without fixing that, the code will never work. But there may be more problems with it. Tried your last change, yet with that it updates the title of the provider. So there were two bugs. Btw: both can easily be found and fixed if you set a breakpoint in `updateProvider` and use the debugger;

Comment: The `undefined` mistake? If so, I've updated the plunker here (http://plnkr.co/edit/APyuCO6k9Q7h4tCnFGdC?p=preview) with your correction above. And this updates the item's `title` on submit. Does that look correct to you? Also, what do you mean by a breakpoint and debugger?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug JavaScript code, which is the best way to be able to dig yourself out of this type of problem going forward. I suggest you google "modern javascript debugging" or something like that to get started.

Comment: I think you're right. It's one area I definitely need to learn about a lot more as it will stop me running into these hurdles. Thanks for the advice, dude!